# Hop schedule for Single hop ale brewing

Tags: hops, hop-utilization, dry-hop, experiments

I am planning on brewing up a handful of quasi-pale ales using only a single hop varietal per batch.  The goal is to get a feel for the bittering, flavor and aroma of some varieties I want to understand better.
I was thinking of a schedule like this.

60min-35IBU
20min-15IBU
5min-5IBU
Dry Hop- (1oz)

I'll figure the IBUs base upon the Alpha content of each variety I plan to use, which is why I didn't list it in ounces.  Except for the dry hop, which will really contirbute no IBUs and why the 5min is so low in IBUs.

I plan to shoot for a 1.048-1.052 OG beer brewed with 90% 2-row, 5% Crystal 60L, and 5% Victory malt.

Here is the question?
Should I drop the 5 minute and just go with more dryhop?
And should I change the time on the flavor addition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great exercise.  Months ago I brewed a single hop brown ale and now I can identify Northern Brewer hops.  That beer was a single bittering addition at 90 minutes, but the idea is the same.

I would keep the aroma addition where it is.  Boiling and dry hopping work differently so you might miss out on something without the last kettle addition.  The flavor addition is also fine.